# Board Save & Close not available in Azure Devops. How to save the board?

Tags: azure-devops

The button is greyed out and does not work

[image]

The reason probably is here:

[image]

But there no explanation what is going on.

Comment: Share the Bug and Diong pages to see the reasons.

Comment: @ShamraiAleksander where do I find these `Bug and Diong` pages?

Comment: There is less content in the screenshot, so it’s hard to tell which page it comes from. Could you please share your specific steps or share the complete screenshot?

Comment: fyi resolution of problems don't belong in your question (I rolled back this edit). This question should be closed, as 1) it's not a programming question and 2) the OP figured out what they did and resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the screenshot, you have turned off the `New Boards Hub` preview feature, and `editing the board setting` after changding process from Agile to Scrum process.

The grey button `save and close` is caused by there are some error on `Bug` and `Doing` column on your 2nd screenshot.

You need to go to the `Bug` and `Doing` tab, fix the error(choose the correct state) like below:
[image]

Then the button is active:

[image]

You can find the details in official doc: [Change a project process from Agile to Scrum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-agile-to-scrum?view=azure-devops)